# Analogue of NotebookDirectory[] for scripts (to get the directory path of my script.m)?

Tags: files-and-directories, scripting

Is there a way to get the script directory from inside a Mathematica script?

I want a function analogue to `NotebookDirectory[]` (which doesn't work for scripts). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

```
DirectoryName @ $InputFileName
```

is the answer, right?

And this will work whether you call it from a package or a notebook interface:

```
parentPath = $InputFileName /. "" :> NotebookFileName[]
parentDir = DirectoryName @ parentPath
```

---

Check:

```
path = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "test.m"}];

Export[
 path,
 "Print @ DirectoryName @ $InputFileName",
 "Text"
 ]

Get @ path
```

> (...)\Local\Temp\

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't work if you call your script (.m) from within the terminal using `wolframscript`

Comment: @Santi could you elaborate, with a script.m file containing only: `Print["test parent dir: ", DirectoryName @ $InputFileName]` I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrLrA.png

Comment: hi @Kuba, ok, you are right, but in the way I was running my scripts it doesn't work. If I do:  `wolfram -script script.m` it works. But if I do `wolframscript -file script.m` it doesn't work. I am on Mathematica 11.1.1 Kernel for Linux x86 (64-bit).

Comment: do you have an idea why this doesn't work with `wolframscript` ?

Comment: @Santi I didn't work with scripts yet so I don't know, I will try to investigate if I find time. You could ask a question on main about that. Just make sure to prepare simple example people can run.

Comment: Is $InputFileName supposed to work in .mt test files? It looks like I'll have to hardcode my paths in my tests.